# Functional testing with phpunit 6.5.1 symfony 3.4 button issue

Tags: php, symfony, twig, phpunit, functional-testing

I am trying to test my small web app with phpunit but Im having difficulty submitting forms and accessing the buttons with the crawler.
I can't seem to login as the node always reports as empty. I believe the issue may be with the submit button, possibly trying to reference it.

```
private $client = null;

 public function setUp()
 {
    $this->client = static::createClient();
    $this->testlogIn();
 }

   public function testLogIn()
{
    $crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '/login');
    $form = $crawler->filter('button#logIn')
      ->form(
            [
              '_username' => 'AdminAccountKyleTest',
              '_password' => 'test'
            ],
            'POST'
        );

    $this->client->submit($form);

    $this->assertContains('Homepage', $crawler->filter('body > div.main > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > h1')->text());
}
```

This is the twig template for the button:

```
  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" id="logIn" 
type="submit">Sign in</button>
```

Does phpunit have an issue when the button is rendered in the twig instead of a SubmitType on a form ?

Comment: I have also tried $form = $crawler->selectButton('Sign in') however this does not work also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test you form using the following snippet:

```
    //selectButton accepts the button id|name|text
    $form = $crawler->selectButton("logIn")->form();

    $form['_username'] = 'AdminAccountKyleTest';
    $form['_password'] = 'test';

    $client->submit($form);

    //follow the form request redirect after login_check
    $client->followRedirect();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment, however, i still get this error. 

1) 
Tests\AppBundle\Controller\DefaultControllerTest::testLogIn
InvalidArgumentException: The current node list is empty.

/swiftcase/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DomCrawler/Crawler.php:565
/swiftcase/tests/AppBundle/Controller/DefaultControllerTest.php:114
/swiftcase/tests/AppBundle/Controller/DefaultControllerTest.php:15

Comment: I think it just cant seem to find the button name or id whatever it may be.

Comment: check your actual response if it actually returns the login page using 
        die($client->getResponse()->getContent()); in the test case

Comment: Hello sorry, basically i needed to give the button a name in the twig instead of an id which i never realised, however thank you for your help, much appreciated.